# how to create loading window while web conncetion is checking in windows form app?

Tags: c#, web, connection

I have a test web connection form in c#. I want to show a loading window while my connection is being checked, and then show the result of checking.

This is my code for testing the web connection:

```
   public bool ConnectionAvailable(string strServer)
   {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest reqFP = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(strServer);

           HttpWebResponse rspFP = (HttpWebResponse)reqFP.GetResponse();
            if (HttpStatusCode.OK == rspFP.StatusCode)
            {
              // HTTP = 200 - Internet connection available, server online
                rspFP.Close();
                return true;
            }
            else
           {
               // Other status - Server or connection not available
                rspFP.Close();
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            // Exception - connection not available
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "Web-url";
        label1.Text = "Checking ...";
        button1.Enabled = false;

        if (ConnectionAvailable(url))
        {
            WebClient w = new WebClient();
            w.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            label1.Text = w.UploadString(url, "post", "SN=" + textBox1.Text);
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = "Conntion fail";
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a windows forms application the user interface runs on one thread, if you try to run a long running process, which checking the web connection might end up being this will cause the form to freeze until it completes the work.

So, I'd start a new thread that does the check. then raise an event to return the result. while all that's happening you can do what you like with the user interface, such as a loading graphic, or even allow the user to continue using features that don't require the internet connection.

Create EventArgs class of your own so you can pass back the result:

```
public class ConnectionResultEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool Available { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your form class, create your event, handlers and the method to action when the event arrives

```
//Create Event and Handler
    public delegate void ConnectionResultEventHandler(object sender, ConnectionResultEventArgs e);
    public event ConnectionResultEventHandler ConnectionResultEvent;

//Method to run when the event has been receieved, include a delegate in case you try to interact with the UI thread
    delegate void ConnectionResultDelegate(object sender, ConnectionResultEventArgs e);
    void ConnectionResultReceived(object sender, ConnectionResultEventArgs e)
    {
        //Check if the request has come from a seperate thread, if so this will raise an exception unless you invoke.
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new ConnectionResultDelegate(ConnectionResultReceived), new object[] { this, e });
            return;
        }

        //Do Stuff
        if (e.Available)
        {
            label1.Text = "Connection Good!";
            return;
        }

        label1.Text = "Connection Bad";
    }
```

Subscribe to the event when your form loads:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Subscribe to the the results event.
        ConnectionResultEvent += ConnectionResultReceived;
    }
```

and then setup the worker thread:

```
//Check the connection
    void BeginCheck()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest reqFP = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://google.co.uk");

            HttpWebResponse rspFP = (HttpWebResponse)reqFP.GetResponse();
            if (HttpStatusCode.OK == rspFP.StatusCode)
            {
                // HTTP = 200 - Internet connection available, server online
                rspFP.Close();

                ConnectionResultEvent(this, new ConnectionResultEventArgs {Available = true});
            }
            else
            {
                // Other status - Server or connection not available
                rspFP.Close();

                ConnectionResultEvent(this, new ConnectionResultEventArgs { Available = false });
            }
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {

            // Exception - connection not available
            //Raise the Event - Connection False
            ConnectionResultEvent(this, new ConnectionResultEventArgs { Available = false });
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //loading graphic, screen or whatever
        label1.Text = "Checking Connection...";

        //Begin the checks - Start this in a new thread
        Thread t = new Thread(BeginCheck);
        t.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking of threading! One thread checks the connection while the other one is showing the loading window. If for example the connection has been established you can notify the other thread and show the result.